# edge labels with boundary in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels, edge

I have the following graph I am trying to replicate with Tikz. I am having trouble creating the square edge label containers. Is there an easy way to do this in tikz?
[image]

**EDIT**

I made a small example incorporating @John Kormylo suggestion:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{circ} = [circle, draw, thick, text centered, minimum size=3em, align=left]

    \begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',node distance = 3cm, thick, auto]
    \node [circ] (s1) {1};
    \node [circ, right =of s1] (s2) {2};
    \node [circ, below = of s1] (s3) at ($(s1)!0.5!(s2)$) {3};

    \path[every node/.style={}]
    (s1) edge[bend left=20] node [very near start] {c} node [midway, below, draw, sloped] {1} node [very near end] {e}  (s2)
    (s1) edge[bend right=20] node [very near start,swap] {d} node [midway, below, draw, sloped] {2} node [very near end,swap] {f}  (s3)
    (s2) edge[bend left=20] node [very near start] {i} node [midway, below, draw, sloped] {3} node [very near end,swap] {g}  (s3);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Result looks like:

[image]

Now I really just need a method to rotate the actual labels within the squares. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm thinking [midway, above, draw, sloped] for the squares, but you will need a separate node to  unrotate the numbers.  A MWE would be useful here.

Comment: Thanks @JohnKormylo ! The squares turned out quite nicely. I added a minimum working example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the node text via `label` to avoid it getting sloped.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[circ/.style={circle, draw, thick, text centered,
        minimum size=3em, align=left},
        >=Stealth,node distance = 3cm, thick, auto,
        box/.style 2 args={edge node={node[sloped,draw,minimum
        size=1.5em,#1,label={[anchor=center]center:#2}]{}}}
        ]
    \node [circ] (s1) {1};
    \node [circ, right =of s1] (s2) {2};
    \node [circ, below = of s1] (s3) at ($(s1)!0.5!(s2)$) {3};

    \path[every node/.style={},->]
    (s1) edge[bend left=20,box={midway,below}{1}]  node [very near start] {c} 
    node [very near end] {e}  (s2)
    (s1) edge[bend right=20,box={midway,below}{2}] node [very near start,swap] {d}  node [very near end,swap] {f}  (s3)
    (s2) edge[bend left=20,box={midway,below}{3}] node [very near start] {i}  node [very near end,swap] {g}  (s3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And since you have so many edge labels you can use the `quotes` library.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending,quotes}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[circ/.style={circle, draw, thick, text centered,
        minimum size=3em, align=left},
        >={Stealth[bend]},node distance = 3cm, thick, auto,
        box/.style={draw,minimum size=1.5em,label={[anchor=center]center:#1}}]
  \node [circ] (s1) {1};
  \node [circ, right =of s1] (s2) {2};
  % the usage below is unusual but efficient
  \node [circ, below = of s1] (s3) at ($(s1)!0.5!(s2)$) {3};

  \path[->]
    (s1) edge[bend left=20,"c" very near start,""' {box=1},"e" very near end] (s2)
    (s1) edge[bend right=20,"d" very near start,""' {sloped,box=2},"e" very near end](s3)
    (s2) edge[bend left=20,"i" very near start,""' {sloped,box=3},"g"' very near end](s3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]